# ARIMA model in Python

Tags: python

I am using ARIMA to do forecasting in Python, following are my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

HSBC = pd.read_csv('HSBC.csv', index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)
HSBC2 = HSBC['Close']
result = seasonal_decompose(HSBC2, model='multiplicative', period = 1)

from pmdarima import auto_arima
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

stepwise_fit = auto_arima(HSBC2, start_p = 1, start_q = 1, 
                      max_p = 3, max_q = 3, m = 12, 
                      start_P = 0, seasonal = True, 
                      d = None, D = 1, trace = True, 
                      error_action ='ignore',    
                      suppress_warnings = True,  
                      stepwise = True) 

train = HSBC2[0:173]
test = HSBC2[173:248]
model = SARIMAX(train, order = (0, 1, 1), seasonal_order =(0,1,1,12)) 
result = model.fit()

start = len(train)
end = len(train) + len(test) - 1
prediction = result.predict(start,end,
                            typ = 'levels').rename("Predictions")  
predictions.plot(legend = True) 
test.plot(legend = True)
```

I am confusing that why the x-axis of prediction plot become number, which supposed to be date like that of test plot.

[image: output of prediction and test plot]

Comment: Can't access the code. Did you data is date indexed?

Comment: Edit your post and copy and past your code on it.

Comment: I have uploaded my code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, this is due you have not specify the frequency of your index. Try this:

```
HSBC.index = pd.date_range(freq='d', start=HSBC.index[0], periods=len(HSBC)
```

Beware that you should frequency='d' if your index is daily spaced

EDIT:

So, the answer was just changing the parameters start and end parameters of the predict method, e.g:

```
start = test['Date'].iloc[0]
end = test['Date'].iloc[-1]
prediction = result.predict(start,end,
                            typ = 'levels').rename("Predictions")
```

Comment: Thank you Snedecor. I have tried using your code, but the result is still the same.

Comment: I am confusing that in test dataset, the data is not indexed but the x-axis still can be date format.

Comment: Have you tried changing start/end parameters in predict method? For example start should be the first date of test data set and test the last.

Comment: You means in here: start = len(train)
                                end = len(train) + len(test) - 1
                                ?

Comment: Nope, you are giving it numbers, try giving it dates!

Comment: Could you mark this as the correct answer? Thank you :)!